# Getting 'Multiple commands produce' error with duplicate output file warning in Xcode 13.0

Tags: swift, cocoapods, deriveddata

I am getting below multiple commands produce error while running the application in Xcode 13.0.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-dsntzothkrspqbfirwzgyvntjirn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework':
1) That command depends on command in Target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' (project 'Pods'): script phase “[CP] Copy XCFrameworks”
2) That command depends on command in Target 'GoogleAppMeasurement-AdIdSupport' (project 'Pods'): script phase “[CP] Copy XCFrameworks”
```

And also getting duplicate output file warning as mentioned below: -

```
duplicate output file '/Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-dsntzothkrspqbfirwzgyvntjirn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy XCFrameworks /Users/asif.raza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-dsntzothkrspqbfirwzgyvntjirn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleAppMeasurement-AdIdSupport.build/Script-CAAD1E7A7F15E98CC87B30D71A33FD1C.sh
```

Could someone please help me out to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Solution found:** After removing below ‘Pods_AppName.framework’ from ‘Link Binary With Libraries’ in Build Phases as showing disabled. Removed all derived data then Clean Build folder and and run.
[image]

Comment: It's likely a problem with overlapping dependencies in the Podfile. Share it here and we'll be better able to help.

Comment: attached screenshot.

Comment: I mean - share the contents in the file - Podfile.

Comment: I found solution. Remove ‘Pods_AppName.framework’ from ‘Link Binary With Libraries’ in Build Phases as showing disabled.
Removed all derived data then Clean Build folder and and run.